# swap 2 erc20 with each other at one method between 2 different user. -- Reentrancy guard problem

Tags: blockchain, solidity, swap, erc20

I know I have to use nonReentrant modifier for this method, but I also know it's wont work can someone tell me what should I do to create a mechanism something like this with safe pattern?

```
function swapTokenToEvolve(uint256 _tokenAmount, uint256 _stageIndex)
    public
    checkStageTime(_stageIndex)
    checkRemainingAmount(_tokenAmount, _stageIndex)
    nonReentrant
    returns (bool)
{
    // get token price from stage ;
    uint256 tokenPrice = salesStages[_stageIndex].price;
    // how many tokens user will get;
    uint256 stableTokenAmount = multiply(_tokenAmount, tokenPrice, decimal);
    // transfer token from buyer to seller;
    require(
        IERC20(currencyToken).transferFrom(
            owner(),
            _msgSender(),
            _tokenAmount
        )
    );
    // transfer token from seller to user;
    require(
        IERC20(token).transferFrom(_msgSender(), owner(), stableTokenAmount)
    );
    salesStages[_stageIndex].liquidity = salesStages[_stageIndex]
        .liquidity
        .sub(_tokenAmount);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

before any "transferFrom" you have to take approve from token owner, on the other hand to prevent "reentrancy" you have to change the variable before any external call, I suggest 2 steps:

1-get approve from the token owner before this function(because msg.sender checked in that) or if you want using in this function user [ERC-20-permit](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20Permit)

2-change your state variable line.`salesStages[_stageIndex].liquidity = salesStages[_stageIndex] .liquidity .sub(_tokenAmount);` before your [external call](https://external%20call).

Answer (score 0):

The `transferFrom` method from ERC20 token is the following:

```
function transferFrom(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
) public virtual override returns (bool) {
    address spender = _msgSender();
    _spendAllowance(from, spender, amount);
    _transfer(from, to, amount);
    return true;
}
```

Where `_spendAllowance` requires the allowance to exists for the transfer amount:

```
function _spendAllowance(
    address owner,
    address spender,
    uint256 amount
) internal virtual {
    uint256 currentAllowance = allowance(owner, spender);
    if (currentAllowance != type(uint256).max) {
        require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: insufficient allowance");
        unchecked {
            _approve(owner, spender, currentAllowance - amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, you do not need to require the `transferFrom`. What you need to do is make sure the contract has enough allowance from both `owner()` (first transfer) and `_msgSender()` (second transfer).

Comment: so if I check allowance first there is no way to reentrance the transaction? I mean Reentrance atack

Comment: What avoids reentrancy in your function is the `nonReentrant` modifier you already included. You shouldn't have to worry about reentrancy once you've done that. Security-wise, you should ensure that both `currencyToken` and `token` are standard ERC20 that do not have malign transfer functions. Why is it not working then? I might be missing the point.

Comment: I read somewhere I can't use nonReentrant  when i have external call in my function and I add this for question. I don't test my method with nonReentrant  modifier.